# Automating Queries In An Access 2010 Database

Tags: database, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have 6 queries in a db that I'm running each night, saving & publishing the file for use elsewhere.  Does anyone know where I can get some direction on setting up to automate this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run them in VBScript and set that to run with the Task Scheduler. Alternatively, kick off the database with a command line switch: /x  macro ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/209207 )

Answer (score 4):

3 Easy steps with no coding:

1. Create a Macro object in Access to run all 6 queries.
2. Drag the Macro object and drop to the desktop or any folder in Windows Explorer. This creates an "executable" shortcut that opens the database and runs the macro.
3. Create a new Scheduled Task to launch the shortcut file.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Create an autoexec macro in your database.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-a-macro-that-runs-when-you-open-a-database-HA010341574.aspx)
   This is just a regular macro, but naming it "autoexec" causes Access to execute it when you open the database (press SHIFT to avoid execution).
   In the macro, you can select actions that you want the macro to perform.
   There is an action that runs queries, and one that closes Access.
   I never created a macro in Access 2010, but in Access 2003 the actions are called `OpenQuery` and `Quit`.
   --> insert six `OpenQuery` actions (one for each of your queries) and one `Quit` action to close Access in the end.
2. Run the database with Windows Task Scheduler.
   It will execute the autoexec macro automatically, which will run all your queries and close Access again.